# PyQt4.QtCore doesn't contain many of its classes and attributes

Tags: python, linux, qt4, pyqt

I have built PyQt4 from source and everything went smoothly until I tried to use some of the classes and attributes located in QtCore. For some reason QtCore is missing a lot of functionality and data that should be there. For example from PyQt4.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR is an import error. There were no errors or warnings given when building the packages and I have also tried with the PyQt packages from yum but I have the same problem.

Has anyone else encountered this problem before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this problem was a conflict in my python path. I had two modules named sip.py in different locations on my python path, the python path was using the first one but I wanted it to use the second one. I removed the first entry from the python path as it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really an `ImportError`, that suggests that it's failing to import the library altogether. Check that it's definitely somewhere that's in your `sys.path`, and that `from PyQt4 import QtCore` works.

If the library exists, and QT_VERSION_STR doesn't exist, it will give you a `NameError` rather than an `ImportError`.

Comment: The library does exist, I can import it but some functionality is missing such as QT_VERSION_STR. It gives an import error but as you said maybe it should give a name error. If I try to access it as PyQt4.QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR it does give an attribute error. I think this is a build issue with PyQt4 but it gives no errors to suggest so.

Comment: Well, if you just import PyQt4, it will give you an attribute error, because that doesn't pull QtCore in. But if your distro's packages are the same, it suggests there's something else wrong. Does `from PyQt4 import QtCore` work? Then what does `dir(QtCore)` give?

Comment: I can import QtCore and using dir on it gives me only part of the functionality that should be there. I seem to get all the functions but none of the classes or global attributes.